# Filter Django DB object with a manipulated keyword

Tags: python, django

I take a timestamp for my Institution class:

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    timestamp_utc = models.DateTimeField()
```

If there is an entry in the DB that has the same year, month and date (not time), then I want to update the value of the entry.  If not, then I want to create a new entry.

The conditional is as follows:

```
 if Institution.objects.filter(timestamp_utc.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")=b['timestamp_utc'].strftime("%Y/%m/%d")).exists():
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception Value: keyword can't be an expression
```

Is there a way to filter the DB object with a manipulated keyword?

Comment: Do you want to filter by time?

Comment: Yes.  I want to filter by today's date essentially to see if an entry already exists.

Comment: If you want to filter only by date why don't you store date and time in differents fields with `DateField` and `TimeField`, then you can use `.combine()` function to create a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just filter by the date range, i.e. time stamps that are great than or equal to the date, and less that the date + 1 day.

```
from datetime import relativedelta
date_start = b['timestamp_utc'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
date_end = (b['timestamp_utc'] + relativedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
if Institution.objects.filter(
   timestamp_utc__gte=date_start, timestamp_utc__lt=date_end
).exists():
```

Comment: What is stored in the DB is a timestamp with year, month, day and time.  Don't I need to manipulate the string in the DB somehow?

Comment: Made numerous edits. If you're storing as a UTC field you can just filter with ISO dates. Your database should know what to do.